# transformation between Map to Set

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, set

in the following code I'm trying to transform between map to set so I used list as a middle since set doesn't allow keys and values
I know there is easier ways to transform between these 2 but I want to know why it gave me "false" when I ran the script

```
void main() {
  List a = [];
  Map info = {"name": "mark", "age": "20"};
  info.forEach((key, value) {
    a.add(value);
  });

  a.toSet;
  print(a is Set);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is printing `false` because the type of your variable `a` is still a `List` object.

If you check the [documentation of the method `toSet`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Iterable/toSet.html) you will see that its prototype is the following:

```dart
Set<E> toSet()
```

The method `toSet` is not changing the type of your variable from `List` to `Set`, its returning a new value which you will have to keep inside another variable.

As mentioned by Yeasin you are declaring your variable `a` as `List`, to convert it to a `Set` object you can either type `a` as `Set` when declaring it:

```dart
Set a = {};
```

or, as you've tried, call the method `toSet()` but you will need to keep the return value in a new variable:

```dart
final mySet = a.toSet();
```

Note that instead of using a `forEach` you could directly convert as a `Set` your map by using the getter `values`:

```dart
Map info = {"name": "mark", "age": "20"};
final a = info.values.toSet();
print(a is Set);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've  declared variable type of `a` as List, Therefor it will only can have list.

To convert set, use `.toSet()`.

Now let say we still want to assign set inside `a` variable. In this case we can use `dynamic` data type.

```dart
void main() {
  dynamic a = [];
  Map info = {"name": "mark", "age": "20"};
  info.forEach((key, value) {
    a.add(value);
  });

  a = a.toSet();
  print(a is Set);
}
```

You can find more about [dart type-system](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system).